# Flutter Push Notification with Firestore Database

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made an messaging app in which messages are saved in firestore database.
Now I want to connect it to Firebase Cloud Messaging Service for sending Notification as soon as new message arrives in firestore databse.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `firebase-admin` package with `cloud functions` to achieve this. Check this link out [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).